# QMake with VS2022

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2022, qmake

Our build process has relied on having .pro files which we convert to .vcxproj files dynamically on the build server. This is done in part to keep the builds cross platform, and because it's easier to track diffs in a .pro file than various settings one might change in visual studio.

The build.bat process looks like this

```
if NOT DEFINED VisualStudioVersion (
   echo "Setting up VC environment"
   call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
   call  "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall" x86_amd64
   )


SET PROFILE=MY.pro
SET VCXPROJ=MY.vcxproj

echo Exporting %PROFILE% to %VCXPROJ%
"%QTDIR%\bin\qmake" -tp vc -o %VCXPROJ% %PROFILE%


MSBuild %VCXPROJ% /p:Configuration=Release  /p:Platform=x64
```

As we move to 2022 I've had some struggles getting the same process to work.

If I use the following to setup my environment:

```
set vsdev=c:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
set varsall=c:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\PROFES~1\VC\AUXILI~1\Build\VCVARS~1.BAT

if  NOT DEFINED VisualStudioVersion (
echo "Setting up VC environment"
call %vsdev%
call %varsall% x86_amd64
)
```

I get the following issue when trying to build my project:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(460,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using
the v141 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2017 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
 [c:\sandbox\RFDMWriter\proj\RFDMWriter.vcxproj]
```

It doesn't seem like QMake knows about the 143 platform I need. I haven't figured out how to edit the mkspecs to teach it.

I've tried targeting QT 6.2.4. It seems like msvc2019_64 is the latest version I can find of QT 6.2.4 - this should be binary compatible with 2022 but it doesn't generate the projects correctly.